# easy and robust way to version WEB API in the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Goal: /**v1**/whatever/path/here.
I am pretty new to the ASP.Net Web API framework and at the begining it seemed to me that the task is easy. 
So I ended up with:

```
public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request) {
        var requestedVersion = ExtractOnlyVersionDigits(request);
        var currentVersionControllers =
            SelectControllersOfRequestedVersion(requestedVersion);
        if (currentVersionControllers.Count() > 0) {
            var appropriateController = currentVersionControllers.First(); // yeah, that is stupid, I know that
            return new HttpControllerDescriptor(
                _configuration,
                appropriateController.Name,
                appropriateController);

    }
```

After 4 hours of coding I realized that it will not work with multiply controllers unsless I map them manually.

So my questiono is: 1) am I misusing this framework? 2) is there a simple way to reuse existing functionality? 3) if not, how can I impelment my version mapping WITHOUT declaring [RoutePrefix] or whatisit on each and very controller/action?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article by Scott Hanselman on versioning API's for ASP.NET

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCoreRESTfulWebAPIVersioningMadeEasy.aspx

Might be worth looking at that instead of trying to grow your own? :-)